# JQuery element CLICK function IF (for each css_attribute = value) then change css value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a JQuery NEWB trying to figure out why this doesn't work. 
HTML:

```
<div class="box" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">div 0</div>
<div class="box" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">div 1</div>
<div class="box">div 2</div>
<button>
<a class="button">
click
</a>
</button>
```

SCRIPT:

```
$(".button").click(function() { 
    $('.box').each(function(i) {
        var color = $(this).css('background-color');
        if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
            $("div#box").css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});
        }
    });
});
```

The actual over all problem is much more complex and this is NOT the actual code, but this is an equivalent based from what solutions I could find on here.

Comment: Change this line. `$("div.box").css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});` the selector is looking for div elements with the ID of box, not the class. `#` is used to target ID and `.` is used to target class

Comment: Your problem may be here there is no Id is specified so can Id to class like this $("div.box").css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});

Comment: `console.log(color)` will show you why it fails. The answer with color comparison is use CSS classes.

Comment: can you use console log on JSFiddle?  Or on a live server?  This particular project is not set up for my local servers.

Comment: What is the element `id="box"`?

Comment: THANK YOU NewToJS - too many hours in front of this screen - I can't believe I bothered you guys over that... How do I mark this solved?  I'm also new to posting on Stack.

Comment: @DM1 The selector to `$("div.box").css` Will change **ALL** div elements with the `class` name of box, not just those with that css property. If you only want to change the css for those that match then use `$(this).css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});` https://jsfiddle.net/9Lpwfck9/

Comment: I get that, NewToJS.  Like I said, this is just a Fiddle "knock-off" based on my real code, which actually affects the appearance of something entirely diferent - thus the Id # vs .class mistake. Thanks for all your help! - I will most likely be back again.

Comment: @DM1 Very welcome! Here to help if/where I can.

Comment: Although, mixing the class with "this" makes it interesting in its iterations:
http://jsfiddle.net/0bdqrqkg/6/

Comment: @DM1 that's because it's looping through each div and is being checked for those CSS properties but also being told to change them. Open up the console and add something in so you can understand it a little better.

Comment: @DM1 var color is defined before the if statements, so any changes you make to the element the next if statement will not be checking the new css value of the element as `color` will still = to the old css value until it loops to the next element where `var color` is run once again.

Comment: @NewToJS Please add your comments into an answer so this can be marked as accepted by the OP.

Answer (score 0):

In your case change your `js` part to below. then it will solve the problem.

> ```
> $(".button").click(function() { 
>     $('.box').each(function(i) {
>
>          var color = $(this).css('background-color');
>          if (color == 'rgb(0, 0, 255)') {
>             $(this).css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});
>         }
>     });
> });
> ```

or else this is how you can do it. refer the working demo and the example code. hope this will help to your.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
</head>

<style type="text/css">



</style>


<body>

<div class="holder">
 <div id="0i" class="box" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">div 0</div>
 <div id="1i" class="box" style="background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);">div 1</div>
 <div id="2i" class="box">div 2</div>
</div>


<button>
<a class="button">
click
</a>
</button>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(".button").click(function() { 
    var the_length = $("div.holder div").length;
    for(var i=0;i<the_length;i++)
    {
     var color_code = $("div #"+i+"i").css("background-color");
     
     if (color_code == "rgb(0, 0, 255)") 
     {
      $("div#"+i+"i").css ({'background-color':'rgb(255, 0, 0)'});
     }
     
    }
});

</script>




</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Sorry Anuradh S, it was actually a mistake between calling the "box" div by  ID instead of CLASS.  Although trying "this" helped me understand the iterations of the function better, it was not the solution for my problem.  It was a simple typo.  I had been up for over 24 hours and I converted a small chink of my code from a bigger script set into something simpler and unrelated. Thanks for responding though.